# Python 2.7: global name 'log' is not defined?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script that worked normally, but out of a sudden I start receiving this error:

```
 File "/home/user/Documents/myscript.py", line 100, in getResults
    results = (log(output_list[1]) * 30)
NameError: global name 'log' is not defined
```

The script worked normally with the same line, but now it does not. I don't have a single clue what has happened here?

Comment: You should show the whole code of `myscript.py`. Where is `log` defined?

Comment: @tasty: There is no such built-in.

Comment: As @alecxe says, please post the whole script. You/someone probably deleted or modified an `import` statement unknowingly.

Comment: As a side note, there's no reason for the extra parentheses around the entire expression, and it makes it harder to read your code (is the `* 30` instead the `log`, or outside?).

Comment: As another side note, your variable names seem pretty misleading. If `some_string` is actually a string, then `some_string[1]` is a single-character string, and if you pass that to `log` you're just going to get a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am guessing that you are trying to use the `math.log` function.

You either need:

```
import math
...
results = (math.log(some_string[1]) * 30)
```

Or:

```
from math import log
...
results = (log(some_string[1]) * 30)
```

You must be missing your import statement.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `import math` at the top of your script.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan 21 2013, 09:25:42)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> math.log(10)
2.302585092994046
```

Comment: This wouldn't solve the problem; `from math import log` would, as would `import math` then `log = math.log`.

Comment: Very true. It might be best to find the name conflict, resolve it, and then change to using this style of import.

Answer (score 0):

At the staring of the code

`from math import log`